# about sending mail from windows mail (gmail) from a linked account

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

I am facing the following problem while using the windows mail app: I have set up my Gmail account on the mail app and I receive all the emails as well as send mails using my Gmail address. But I have linked one IMAP account to my Gmail and so while using Gmail from the Gmail app or browser I can send mail using my institute id (IMAP). But I am unable to do so using the mail app (here I am talking about sending mail from my other id using Gmail login, I know I can set up the IMAP address on my mail app. But I am using the IMAP account using dot forward so I don't want to do that.)

Thanks in advanced for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test on Gmail and its linked account in Outlook desktop client, it doesn't work and it seems to be by design. I'm afraid that if you want to send from another account instead of your Gmail account, you need to add the IMAP account together with Gmail in a profile.

Comment: That's sad. Is there any alternate mail client which allows this? The windows client is nice to use otherwise, but no point if I can't send mail using my institute id.